# How to turn an array of years into an array of months in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of years:

```
[2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009]
```

How can I turn this into an array containing each month of those years?

```
[2013-12, 2013-11, 2013-10, 2013-09...]
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`Enumerable#flat_map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map):

```
years = [2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009]
years.flat_map { |year|
    12.downto(1).map { |month|
        sprintf("%04d-%02d", year, month) # OR "%04d-%02d" % [year, month]
    }
}
# => ["2013-12", "2013-11", "2013-10", .., "2009-02", "2009-01"]
```

Comment: Whats the difference between map and flat_map?

Comment: @stevanity, `[[1,2],[2,3]].map{|x|x}` yields `[[1, 2], [2, 3]]`, while  `[[1,2],[2,3]].flat_map{|x|x}` yields `[1, 2, 2, 3]`. Follow the link in the answer for more detail.

Comment: `12.downto(1).map` looks cleaner.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much! I added `month = sprintf('%02d', month)` to account for single digit months as well.

Comment: @Stefan, Yes, it is. I updated the code to use `12.downto(1)`. Thank you for comment.

Comment: @falsetru Oh okay. But why do you use it here?

Comment: @stevanity, Because OP want flat array as a result.

Comment: @Tintin81, Ah, I missed that.

Comment: @falsetru [2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009].flat_map{|x| x} does not equals [2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009].map{|x| x} ??

Comment: @stevanity, `[2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009].flat_map{|x| x}` produces `[2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009]`.

Comment: @falsetru `[2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009].map{|x| x} also produces [2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009]` right?

Comment: @stevanity, Try `[2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009].map { |year| 12.downto(1).map { |month| "%04d-%02d" % [year, month] } }`

Comment: Ohh!! right. It has an iteration inside. SO flat_map will finally flatten the result is it? thanks!!

Comment: @stevanity, `flat_map` is different from `flatten`. Try `[1,2,3].flat_map{|x| [[[x]]] }` and `[1,2,3].map{|x| [[[x]]] }.flatten`.

Answer (score 8):

Using [`Array#product`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-product) to combine years and months:

```
years = [2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009]
months = [*1..12].reverse
#=> [12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

years.product(months).map { |y, m| "%d-%02d" % [y, m] }
#=> ["2013-12", "2013-11", "2013-10", "2013-09", "2013-08", "2013-07", "2013-06", "2013-05", "2013-04", "2013-03", "2013-02", "2013-01", "2012-12", "2012-11", "2012-10", "2012-09", "2012-08", "2012-07", "2012-06", "2012-05", "2012-04", "2012-03", "2012-02", "2012-01", "2011-12", "2011-11", "2011-10", "2011-09", "2011-08", "2011-07", "2011-06", "2011-05", "2011-04", "2011-03", "2011-02", "2011-01", "2010-12", "2010-11", "2010-10", "2010-09", "2010-08", "2010-07", "2010-06", "2010-05", "2010-04", "2010-03", "2010-02", "2010-01", "2009-12", "2009-11", "2009-10", "2009-09", "2009-08", "2009-07", "2009-06", "2009-05", "2009-04", "2009-03", "2009-02", "2009-01"]
```

Comment: Haha stole the show! :D

Comment: Wow, this is even cooler. Thank you! I am using `months = (1..12).to_a.reverse` for brevity, though.

Comment: *+1* although...Is this bad `years.product(months).map { |a| a.join("-") }` ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit that doesn't prepend `0` to single digit months.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from @Stefan,

```
years = [2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009]
years.map(&:to_s).product([*'-01'..'-12'].reverse).map(&:join)
```